# Reading a specific Docker env_file for a container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I have a project with a `.env` file at the root of a Maven project that contains project related information. I want to have a separate `env` file called `.creds.env` in a module directory in the project so that I can add it to `.gitignore`. The `.creds.env` file contains a user name and password in the following format:

```
USER_NAME=user
USER_PASSWORD=password
```

In `docker-compose.yml`, I have the following to read the `.creds.env` file for the service:

```
  myservice:
    env_file:
      - ./module/.creds.env
    container_name: myservice
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./module/Dockerfile
      args:
        USER_NAME: ${USER_NAME}
        USER_PASSWORD: ${USER_PASSWORD}
```

But the username and password are only being read from the root `.env` file and not from the module `.creds.env`

The project structure is like below:

```
|__ .env
|__ docker-compose.yml
|__ module
     |__ Dockerfile
     |__ .creds.env
```

I need help figuring out how to read the `.creds.env` file for the `myservice` container and continue to read the `.env` file for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `USER_NAME` and `USER_PASSWORD` in the root `.env` file.

Sounds like you can assume that your environments will always include the `.creds.env` file.

If you need a default value that you currently reference in `.env`, you may be able to use shell parameter substitution in your compose file:

```
  myservice:
    env_file:
      - ./module/.creds.env
    container_name: myservice
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./module/Dockerfile
      args:
        USER_NAME: ${USER_NAME:-user}
        USER_PASSWORD: ${USER_PASSWORD:-mypass}
```